# How to get only one record for the minimum wage employee from each department? DB2

Tags: sql, db2, greatest-n-per-group

I barely just started on database languages, so I do not know anything about JOIN, PARTITION, ETC. but this is what I have so far.

What I tried:

```
SELECT MIN(SALARY) AS "MIN SALARY", WORKING.DID, ENAME
  FROM DEPARTMENT, EMPLOYEE, WORKING
 WHERE WORKING.EID = EMPLOYEE.EID
 GROUP BY WORKING.DID, ENAME;
```

```
Result:
 MIN SALARY DID ENAME
 ---------- --- ------
      10000 101 Dustin
      15000 102 Bob
      20000 102 David
      10000 102 Dustin
      10000 103 Alex
       8000 103 Alice
       7000 103 Mike
```

What I want:

```
 MIN SALARY DID ENAME
 ---------- --- ------
      10000 101 Dustin
      10000 102 Dustin
       7000 103 Mike
```

Table structures:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
    EID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    ENAME VARCHAR(25),
    SALARY DECIMAL,
    PRIMARY KEY (EID)
);

CREATE TABLE WORKING (
    EID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    DID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    STIME DATE,
    FOREIGN KEY (EID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE (EID),
    FOREIGN KEY (DID) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT (DID),
    PRIMARY KEY (EID, DID)
);

CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT (
    DID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    DNAME VARCHAR(10),
    DADDRESS VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (DID)
);
```

[ER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnb9N.png)

Comment: You select from three tables which is a three table join but you just have one join condition WORKING.EID = EMPLOYEE.EID - so it is a cartesian join with the department table - not a good idea generally. Show the table structures

Comment: You should always specify a table alias for all participating columns to not make others guessing. It’s regarding SALARY and ENAME columns. What if multiple employees of the same department have the minimum wage in the department? Do you want to have all of them in the output or just some arbitrary one of them?

Comment: Just updated the post. 
MichaelTiefenbacher - I am not sure what is a cartesian join.
 @MarkBarinstein I suppose I would like all of them.

Comment: It is 2020.  Why is anyone still using archaic join syntax?

Comment: Is your DBMS MySQL or DB2?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan DB2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prefer using online analytical processing(`OLAP`) functions such as `DENSE_RANK()` to get the desired result easily

```
SELECT Q.SALARY, Q.DID, Q.ENAME 
  FROM
  (
   SELECT E.SALARY, W.DID, E.ENAME,
          DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY W.DID ORDER BY E.SALARY) AS DR
     FROM WORKING W
     JOIN DEPARTMENT D
       ON D.DID = W.EID
     JOIN EMPLOYEE E
       ON E.EID = W.EID
   ) Q
  WHERE DR = 1
```

in which explicit `JOIN` syntax, the syntax having comma-seperated tables is considered as old-deprecated one , is used. Using (`INNER`)`JOIN` is enough for your case, whereas there may be cases needing `OUTER` (`LEFT`-`RIGHT` or `FULL`) `JOIN`s.

Within an analytic function, `PARTITION` Clause is used to express the `GROUPING BY` criteira. Based on the ascending `ORDER` for the `salary`, we'll get the minimum ones to be filtered out through the results coming from the `DENSE_RANK()` function with values equal to one.

By using this method, you can get all the employees with the minimum salaries even there are more than one person for each department.

Moreover, better to alias the tables by their name's first character(or by two or three chars contained within their names depending on the common chars. for the first letters) in order to qualify the columns within the query rather than using whole names.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use the `DEPARTMENT` table in the statement.
While using OLAP functions is preferable way and generally provides better performance, there is another method not using OLAP functions based on rejoining base tables to a sub-select with grouped result, where we get department minimum salary.  We rejoin these department minimums back to `WORKING` & `EMPLOYEE` picking up employees with the department minimum salary only.

```
SELECT G.DID, G.SALARY, E.ENAME
FROM
(
SELECT W.DID, MIN(E.SALARY) SALARY
FROM WORKING W
JOIN EMPLOYEE E ON E.EID = W.EID
GROUP BY W.DID
) G
JOIN WORKING  W ON W.DID = G.DID
JOIN EMPLOYEE E ON E.EID = W.EID AND E.SALARY = G.SALARY;
```